# Dataframe : Group by day and set values in a specific column after the first occurrence

Tags: python, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
                        column1     column2 column3     Filter
2000/01/02 13:35        2.55651     0.1275  0.198       1.0
2000/01/03 14:35        3.30585     0.9425  0.009       1.0
2000/01/04 16:30        3.40865     1.7897  0.515       1.0
2000/01/05 14:15        2.96273     0.6266  0.506       1.0
2000/01/07 14:40        2.75470     0.1724  0.405       1.0
2000/01/07 15:40        2.50288     0.4133  0.075       **1.0**
2000/01/09 14:35        2.20984     0.7232  0.818       1.0
2000/01/09 16:00        2.21001     0.2815  0.160       **1.0**
```

and I want to set to zero the duplicates of the "filter" column after the first occurence inside each day. In this example I  put ** in  the values I want to  set them to zero. The others are ok.
I'd like use loc function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always attach code in text and never a snippet or screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this by making a temporary column that just has the date (not the whole datetime) and then use `df.duplicated()` to mark the subsequent occurrences of the date in another temporary column, and then use that flag to drive changing the Filter column

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('testdf.csv') #put your real filepath here
df.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'datetime'},inplace=True) # I renamed that first column, just for fun
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'],format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M') #changes the format from a string to a datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']).dt.date # makes a new column with jsut the date
df['Duplicate?'] = df.duplicated(subset='date',keep='first') #makes a new column called duplicated. first instance is False and all next instances are True
df.loc[df['Duplicate?'] == True,'Filter'] = 0 #changes Filter to 0 when Duplicated is True
df = df.drop(columns=['date','Duplicate?']) #drops our temporary date and Duplicated columns
print(df)
```